# Access Violation in TDictionary<Variant, Record>

Tags: delphi, tree, associative-array, tdictionary, delphi-xe8

I just wrote a very simple class to test the TDictionary<> Class in Delphi XE8.

When i try to show the records that i added, it brings me an Access Violation error, i don't understand why?

Here is my class

```
unit Unit3;

interface

 uses
  Classes, System.SysUtils, System.Types, REST.Types, System.JSON, Data.Bind.Components,
  System.RegularExpressions, System.Variants,
  Generics.Collections, FMX.Dialogs {$IFDEF DEBUG}, CodeSiteLogging{$ENDIF};

type

  TAArray2 = class;

  PTRec=^TRec;

  TRec = class
  public
    Key : Variant;
    isRequired : boolean;
    Value : Variant;
    OldValue : Variant;
    JSON : string;
    Items : TAArray2;
    procedure Add(Key : Variant ; Value: TRec);
  end;

   TAArray2 = class(TDictionary<Variant, TRec>)
   private
     function Get(Index: variant): TRec;
   public
     destructor Destroy; override;
     procedure Add(Key : Variant ; Value: TRec);
     property Items[Cle : Variant]: TRec read Get; default;
   end;

implementation

procedure TRec.Add(Key : Variant ; Value: TRec);
begin
  if not(assigned(items)) then
    self.Items := TAArray2.Create;
  Items.Add( Key, Value);
  showmessage(inttostr(items.Count)); // this show 1 means items is instanciate and contain the proper data
end;

function TAArray2.Get(Index: Variant): TRec;
begin
  Result := inherited items[Index]
end;

end.
```

Then i'm using this code to test it : (a form with 1 TButton and 1 TMemo)

```
procedure TForm1.ShowAssocArray2(AAA : TAArray2 ; Level : integer);
var
  s : string;
  MyRec : TRec;
begin
  for MyRec in AAA.Values Do
  begin
    FillChar(s, Level * 4, ' ');
    memo1.Lines.Add(s + string(MyRec.Key) + ' = ' + string(MyRec.Value));
    if MyRec.Items.Count > 0 then  // ERROR HERE
      ShowAssocArray2(MyRec.items, Level + 1);   // recursive for childrens
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  MyList : TAArray2;
  MyRec : TRec;
  i : Integer;
begin
  MyList := TAArray2.Create;
  for i := 0 to 9 do
  begin
    MyRec := TRec.Create;
    MyRec.Value := 'Value_' + inttostr(i);
    MyRec.Key := 'No_' + inttostr(i);
    MyList.Add(MyRec.Key, MyRec);
  end;
  // subitem
  MyRec := TRec.Create;
  MyRec.Value := 'test' + inttostr(i);
  MyRec.Key := 'test' + inttostr(i);
  MyList.Items['No_3'].Add('Extra', MyRec);

  memo1.Lines.Add('Nb of Record : ' + inttostr(MyList.Count));

  ShowAssocArray2(MyList, 0);

end;
```

I tried many way : MyRec.Items.Count  or MyRec.Values.Count or MyRec.Items.Values.count... i always have an error i don't understand why?

Comment: Should be the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29906723/delphi-xe8-bug-in-tlistt-need-workaround

Comment: IT's not exaclty the same.. he is asking why it's not sorted.. and don't have recursive TREE data in it.

Comment: No, Fabien, he's not asking why it's not sorted. He's asking why his list doesn't have the contents he expected. The answer is that there's a bug in Delphi XE8's library. It's possible the same bug affects you. It's also possible the library includes other bugs of a similar nature.

Comment: This leaks badly, and still you misuse inheritance.

Comment: I don't think this is the same as the XE8 Insert bug

Comment: Why do i misuse inheritance ? i found some kind code sample they do it this way ? what is wrong please ?  (it work properly if i don't add subitems)...

Comment: You inherite from TDictionary, but why are you rewriting the methods? It looks like you are going to paint a red flower in red to get a red flower ... well it is already red, you do not need to paint

Comment: ah you speak about destructor and and Add method ? yes you are right, but the complete code will be more complex... it's just a minimal structure. so i did make a test to commenting thoses methods, and it still bring a access violation !... the weird thing is i know that my subitems containt 1 data and the items TAArray2 is instanciate. So why access violation (which is more when try to access a non instanciate object).

Comment: It's a mistake to inherit because doing so exposes all inherited methods. They don't all make sense. Use encapsulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a stripped version which executes:

```
program Project20;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,Generics.Collections,StrUtils;


type
  TAArray2 = class;

  TRec = class
  public
    Key : Variant;
    Value : Variant;
    Items : TAArray2;
    procedure Add(Key : Variant ; Value: TRec);
  end;

   TAArray2 = class(TDictionary<Variant, TRec>)
   private
     function Get(Index: variant): TRec;
   public
     destructor Destroy; override;
     //procedure Add(Key : Variant ; Value: TRec);
     property Items[Cle : Variant]: TRec read Get; default;
   end;

procedure TRec.Add(Key : Variant ; Value: TRec);
begin
  if not(assigned(items)) then
    self.Items := TAArray2.Create;
  Items.Add( Key, Value);
  WriteLn(inttostr(items.Count)); // this show 1 means items is instanciate and contain the proper data
end;

destructor TAArray2.Destroy;
begin

  inherited;
end;

function TAArray2.Get(Index: Variant): TRec;
begin
  Result := inherited items[Index]
end;

procedure ShowAssocArray2(AAA : TAArray2 ; Level : integer);
var
  s : string;
  MyRec : TRec;
begin
  s := DupeString(' ',Level * 4);
  for MyRec in AAA.Values Do
  begin
    WriteLn(s + string(MyRec.Key) + ' = ' + string(MyRec.Value));
    if Assigned(MyRec.Items) then // <-- Test if Items is assigned
     if MyRec.Items.Count > 0 then 
      ShowAssocArray2(MyRec.items, Level + 1);   // recursive for childrens
  end;
end;

var
  MyList : TAArray2;
  MyRec : TRec;
  i : Integer;
begin
  MyList := TAArray2.Create;
  for i := 0 to 9 do
  begin
    MyRec := TRec.Create;
    MyRec.Value := 'Value_' + inttostr(i);
    MyRec.Key := 'No_' + inttostr(i);
    MyList.Add(MyRec.Key, MyRec);
  end;
  // subitem
  MyRec := TRec.Create;
  MyRec.Value := 'test' + inttostr(i);
  MyRec.Key := 'test' + inttostr(i);
  MyList.Items['No_3'].Add('Extra', MyRec);

  WriteLn('Nb of Record : ' + inttostr(MyList.Count));

  ShowAssocArray2(MyList, 0);
  ReadLn;
end.
```

The call to `FillChar()` was replaced with `DupeString()`, since no memory was allocated for the string before `FillChar()`.

There is also a test for `Assigned(MyRec.Items)` that resolves the case when Items are unassigned, **which was the cause of your access violation**.

This executes, but I have not analyzed if the result is what you want.
Don't forget to make sure there are no memory leaks as well.

The printout:

```
1
Nb of Record : 10
No_4 = Value_4
No_3 = Value_3
    test10 = test10
No_9 = Value_9
No_7 = Value_7
No_8 = Value_8
No_1 = Value_1
No_2 = Value_2
No_5 = Value_5
No_0 = Value_0
No_6 = Value_6
```

Answer (score 0):

You never create the dictionary in the TREC because you never call the add function on the TREC which creates it.

Comment: self.items := TAArray2.create ?? so it's created no ?

Comment: I added showmessage in Add method as u can see it's instanciate and it's show 1 item added...

Comment: The TREC.Add method doesn't do it because it is never called except on the last record you added.  You would have to see one message for each

Comment: record that was added.  Only the No_3 Rec has a TAArray2 created.  The rest of the TREC have unassigned Lists.

Comment: you could check if Assigned(myRec.Items) and myRec.Items.Count>0 then